# Do I need this code? OpenGL on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL for iOS and I found some old code that I was trying to test out and when I try to run it I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

This is the code:

```
- (void) initGL
{
    RendererInfo renderer;
    // Query renderer capabilities that affect this app's rendering paths
    renderer.extension[APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot] =
    (0 != strstr((char *)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot"));
    renderer.extension[IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888] =
    (0 != strstr((char *)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888"));
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &renderer.maxTextureSize);
}
```

From what I have read these are now obsolete in the current versions of OpenGL, is this correct and is there any need to update this code?

Answer (score 0):

The extensions might be obsolte but the code isn't.

`glGetString` and `glGetIntegerv` is standard in OpenGL therefore you must have a error in your code, i'm not a Objective-C coder but this looks like OpenGL is not initialized or some off the object access is invalid ( for example by accessing a `null`/`nil` object ).